# Angle between vectors atan2(y2,x2) - atan2(y1,x1) explanation

Tags: math, vector, graphics, lua

So while playing with the game framework Love2D lua engine I noticed the following formula inside HUMPS vector code (https://github.com/vrld/hump/blob/master/vector.lua):

```
return atan2(self.y, self.x) - atan2(other.y, other.x)
```

Note: atan2 is described here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2
:basically it is a safe `atan` function that protects against divide by zero and some other `atan` pitfalls - to my understanding.

I've been drawing some graphs of two separate vectors and trying to figure out how someone would come up with a formula like this. The context for this formula, for me at least, is rotating an image (`image_pos`) to where the mouse has clicked (`mouse_pos`).

Can anyone please ELI5 how this formula was derived/how it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the picture it is the difference of angles between two vectors.

[image]

`atan2(self.y, self.x) == \beta`

`atan2(other.y, other.x) == \alpha`

Hence:

`atan2(self.y, self.x) - atan2(other.y, other.x) == \theta`

Comment: I see. Thank you for the explanation + diagram!